# non-singleton PresenterWidgets/Views in GWTP project

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I'm using GWT with the [GWTP framework](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/) in my projects.
Until now all presenters/views where of type singleton (one dedicated window for each implementation type). Now i have a special (document) window where i want to create a new presenter/view (window) for each document the user wants to open.

GWTP class `com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule` contains methods for binding non-singleton PresenterWidgets/Views, for example  with a PresenterWidget factory;

[image]

But i cannot find any documentation or examples about this GWTP PresenterWidget factory usages. How do i implement this PresenterWidget factories?

Comment: Bind a regular PresenterWidget using `bindPresenterWidget()` and bind a singleton using `bindSingletonPresenterWidget`. When you need more than one of the non-singleton type, inject a `Provider<MyPresenterWidget>` instead of a plain `MyPresenterWidget` and call its `get()` method each time you need a new instance.

Comment: That easy? I'll try ... What about the above PresenterWidget factory option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between using com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget and com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter when implementing your own presenter classes.

When using Presenter (with a PresenterProxy), GWTP handles the presenter as singleton.

```
public class MyPresenter extends Presenter<MyPresenter.MyView, MyPresenter.MyProxy>
```

When using PresenterWidget the presenter will be instantiated multiple times (like a Spring prototype scope)

```
public class MyPresenter extends PresenterWidget<MyPresenter.MyView>
```

Then use com.google.inject.Provider get() to instantiate the presenter. When using PresenterWidget it will result in multiple instances. When using Presenter the singleton presenter is returned. For example:

```
@Inject
MySecondPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MySecondView view, MySecondProxy proxy, Provider<MyPresenter> myProvider) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, RevealType.Root);
    setMyProvider(myProvider);
}
```

and

```
MyPresenter p = getMyProvider().get();
getView().addMyPresenter(p);
```

Hope this helps